# What is the R equivalent function for foreach x in... in Stata

Tags: r, label, stata

In Stata if I want to loop over several variables and label all of them I do the following

```
foreach x in a c z t s {
cap label drop `x'
label define `x' 1 "Yes" 2 "No"
label values `x' `x'
}
```

Please can someone tell me how do I do this in R?

Comment: FWIW in Stata it would be easier to avoid a loop and just go `label def yesno 1 "Yes" 2 "No"` followed by `label  values a c t z s yesno`. That doesn't drop existing value labels; it just ignores them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R does not have "labels" in the sense that Stata does, nor does it distinguish types of for loops (as in Stata's `forvalues` and `foreach`). You can work with factor variables, which are somewhat similar to labeled numeric values (and additionally behave like Stata's `i.` prefix notation in its modelling commands). You can create factor variables out of your existing data in a manner fairly similar to your Stata code.

I'm going to work from the assumption that you have a data frame called `dat` that contains the variables named `a`, `c`, `z`, `t`, `s`, and possibly other variables. If so, then you want to loop over the names of the variables:

```
for (i in c("a", "c", "z", "t", "s")) {
    dat[[i]] <- factor(dat[[i]], levels = 1:2, labels = c("Yes", "No"))
}
```

If these names are unique in the data frame (which they probably are), you can alternatively loop over the positions of the variables in the data frame with:

```
pos <- match(c("a", "c", "z", "t", "s"), names(dat))
for (i in pos) {
    dat[[i]] <- factor(dat[[i]], levels = 1:2, labels = c("Yes", "No"))
}
```

Were these the only variables in your dataset, you can use `lapply` and a little cheat notation:

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, factor, levels = 1:2, labels = c("Yes", "No"))
```

There are two add-on packages that provide more Stata-like labelling functionality: [labelled](https://cran.r-project.org/package=labelled) and [Hmisc](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Hmisc), which may be worth exploring. But, in most cases, factors will probably give you what you want.